# Up to date ExactTarget / MarketingCloud documentation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, documentation

I have been referencing this documentation but it seems like these are a little out dated, is this the case? If so could someone point me to the more updated version?

https://help.exacttarget.com/de-AT/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/

I know there are other docs that talk about the fuelsdk and such, but they don't have the exhaustive list of objects and their attributes.

To give an instance:

when looking at `TriggeredSendDefinition`, in the documentation there are the fields:

```
SendWindowOpen
SendWindowClose
```

However when I try to retrieve these attributes of `emailTriggers`, I get an error saying :

```
 AttributeError: TriggeredSendDefinition instance has no attribute 'SendWindowOpen'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you point to a particular thing in the documentation that you see as outdated? Looks like the `en-US` docs are identical to the `de-AT` docs - so it's not language related...

Comment: I didn't even realize I wasn't using the US version, but like you said they they are identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not too much that's changed in the SOAP API for many years, so, for SOAP, that's about the best source of documentation (however frustrating). The full list of objects and properties can be fond in the WSDL...

https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

For the newer REST based API, the best place to head for is here:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html

There's a little bit of overlap between the two flavours of API, but generally, the newer SFMC products release REST APIs, but SOAP is the way to go for Email. That's largely the reason for the SDK - it adds a layer of abstraction from the specific underlying API you're using.

The V2.0 REST API is due to provide a broader coverage of the established applications (if and when it's released).

Comment: Thanks, OK yeah thats what I figured. I'd upvote but I'm to much of a noob (no rep).